# Iterating through text in p tag kills all html that was in the p tag

Tags: jquery

I am using this jquery code to to look inside a

tag and replace the word image with a span tag wrapped around it. The problem is my code is killing any other html thats in the `<p>` tag.

Here is my code

```
$('p').each(
   function() {
       var text = $(this).text();
       var spanText = text.replace('image', '<span class="bText">image</span>');
       $(this).html(spanText);
   }
);
```

Here is html before its applied

```
<p>
I have an image.
<br>
There is a link <a target="_blank" href="https://mysite.com">mylink</a>
     </p>
```

After jquery

```
<p>I have an <span class="bText">image</span>. There is a link mylink </p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`html()` <sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead:

```
var text = $(this).html();
```

[`text()` <sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/text/), as the name suggests, only gets the text content, no HTML tags.

**Further information:**

If you pass a string to [`replace` <sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), only the first occurrence of that string will be replaced. If you want to replace all occurrences, you need a [*regular expression* <sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions) with the `g`lobal flag.

---

Your code could be shortened to (requires jQuery 1.4):

```
$('p').html(function(i, html) {
    return html.replace(/image/g, '<span class="bText">image</span>');
    // or /\bimage\b/g if you e.g. don't want to match `preimage`
});
```

Comment: can you give me the full code sample? Do I still use the var text=$(this).html()?

Comment: @Nick LaMarca: You can either just replace `$(this).text();` with `$(this).html();` in your code or use the second code snippet I posted, this already is the full code.

Comment: your code works in ie but breaks and wont load the page in firefox.

Comment: @Nick LaMarca: That is hard to believe. Do you have a public link to access the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
//mine from scratch - works in chrome, ie, and firefox
$("p").each(function(){
    var html = $(this).html();
    var newHtml = html.replace("image","<span style='font-weight:bold;'>image</span>");
    $(this).html(newHtml);
});
//end
```

in your code change

```
var text = $(this).text();
```

for

```
var text = $(this).html();
```

hope this helps.

Comment: var text = $(this).text(); works, var text = $(this).html(); works in ie but breaks the page and nothing displays in firefox

Comment: written my own and tested in all modern browsers.^^posted above^^ no idea why yours would break in fire fox!! is it throwing any errors?